# How to programatically seek to a particular position/progress in DefaultTimeBar of Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-video-player

Exo player has a widget that handles the progress called
`DefaultTimeBar`

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Using this how-to programmatically seek to a particular position like 50% in android**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through inspecting the source code, it seems like `DefaultTimeBar`calls `update()` constantly to retrieve `bufferedPosition`and `position` and draw the view accordingly. But it also has a couple of functions that call `update()` themselves and redraw everything. It is first initialized under the hood with a `context` and a few other parameters like `AttributeSet`.

From here, it really depends on what you're willing to do with it. If you want to just seek the position in ExoPlayer (which I assume you already know), you can just call this

```
    val desiredPosition = simpleExoPlayer.duration / 2.toLong() // 50%
    simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(desiredPosition)
```

However, if you're miscellaneously using the view as a `Custom View` and wanna update your DefaultTimeBar on your own. You need to understand how to instantiate it. Our `DefaultTimeBar` will receive `position` and `bufferedPosition` value updates constantly from the class that instantiated it to begin with; `PlayerControlView`.

Let's break it down quickly, how a DefaultTimeBar is instantiated and updated:
**1- Instantiation:**

```
    val timeBar: DefaultTimeBar = DefaultTimeBar(context, null, 0, playbackAttrs)
```

As you can see, it takes a `context`, a `@Nullable AttributeSet`, a `defStyleAttr` and a `@Nullable timeBar AttributeSet`. Of course this can be a little bit confusing at first, but for starters, try going with the sample line of code above to instantiate it. The `playbackAttrs` in the constructor are the same playbackAttrs passed from SimpleExoPlayer to PlayerControlView in order to instantiate it. If playbackAttrs are still a cause of confusion, please inspect the source code of `SimpleExoPlayer`.

**2- Updating positions:** After you have instantiated your DefaultTimeBar, you can constantly call these two functions on the instance you have

```
      timeBar.setPosition(position)
      timeBar.setBufferedPosition(bufferedPosition)
```

**3- Modifying a DefaultTimeBar view that is inflated from the XML:** I have no particular experience howsoever with manipulating the DefaultTimeBar, but I assume you can just pass the generated view as a DefaultTimeBar and store it in a variable, that is:

```
    val timeBar: DefaultTimeBar = findViewById(R.id.defaulttimebar) as DefaultTimeBar
```

This MAY or MAY NOT work. DefaultTimeBar extends "View" so the casting may or may not work.

If you wanna seek to a particular position, always make sure you know the target position (For example, a result of a user-induced seeking), then call setPosition to update the DefaultTimeBar.

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted for the valuable source of information and nicely described answer.

I ended up solving the problem by `forwarding` the `exoplayer` `player` object and that inturn handled progress of the `DefaultTimeBar` :)